# How can I use OAuth2 if I can't determine what redirect URI we will require in production?

Tags: angular, spring, azure, oauth-2.0, office365

I have a software project I'd like to add Office 365 connectivity to.  For security purposes, OAuth2 is required to retrieve mailboxes and such from the cloud.  I can set a redirect URI in Azure which (if hard coded) will work in development, but in production, we do not know and cannot enumerate all of the different places this server will be deployed to.  Thus we cannot enter a static redirect URI into Azure.

Is there any way around this problem?  Redirect URI wildcards are not permitted in the OAuth2.0 standard (RFC-6749)

I am working with Angular 7 for the client layer and Spring 5+ as our backend.  I tried resolving the current redirect URI dynamically both in the client/server sides, but it doesn't change the fact that Azure requires the redirect URI preset in the application.

Edit: in addition to this information above, it is important to note that we cannot use implicit or password flow to solve this problem.  Any other OAuth2 work flow is ok though.

Comment: Create an app registration per environment ?

Comment: This won't work for us, sadly (or thankfully?) we have a lot of customers who've deployed our solution

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have the production service deployed to multiple locations to support automatic failover.

What to do will depend on your exact architecture in play.

If your failover mechanism supports routing based on a single incoming DNS name then use that name as the redirect URI and let it handle the routing.

If you can't achieve that then deploy a service such as [Azure Application Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/overview) and use that to distribute HTTP traffic to your production servers based on a single entry point.

Comment: Sort of, we have customers who deploy our application wherever they want as a web app frontend for our software.  So we cannot be sure of where the application is located

Comment: The you'll need to have a mechanism for registering those services by some means. The redirect URI is handling tokens so you want to ensure they are trusted!